# Delphi Delete file - show message file is busy

Tags: delphi, winapi

I have an application that allows to perform some basic actions on file like open and delete. How can I show the same windows message as in the screenshot below when someone try to delete a file opened in any other application?

[image]

Comment: You don't have to. The OS will do that for you.

Comment: no, using function DeleteFile won't show that message

Comment: Related: [How do I find out which process has a file open?](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20120217-00/?p=8283/).

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Use `SHFileOperation` or `IFileOperation` to delete the file. This routes through the same code that the shell uses, and providing that you don't disable error UI then you will receive the standard dialogs in case of failure.